# Eclipse is not running

Tags: linux-mint, eclipse

I have `org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261` installed in my pc and yesterday I upgraded my linux mint 18.3 to 19. after that eclipse stopped working showing error message

> An error has occured. See the log file

I have reinstalled it but it was not Beneficial.
tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920016/eclipse-crashes-an-error-has-occurred-see-the-log-file) but that's also worth.

This is the log

```
!SESSION Tue Jul 17 08:50:57 IST 2018 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-07-17 08:50:57.425
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:609)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:926)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:871)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Bug #891956

This sounds like your issue, titled: [Debian Bug report logs - #891956
eclipse no starting -ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=891956).

the suggestion in that bug was to do this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libequinox-osgi-java
```

> The debug output claimed that the framework has been found, but this
>   was  a lie since:
>   /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar was missing.

#### Bug #898086

Based on the stack trace there's also this bug titled: [Debian Bug report logs - #898086 Missing symlink of org.eclipse.osgi jar](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=898086).

```
=== Log file ===
This is the log file:
!SESSION Fri Jun 15 09:10:34 CEST 2018
-----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-06-15 09:10:34.504
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
=== End of log file ===
```

This looks like your exact issue. This particular bug is still active and has no resolution or workaround.

Comment: @UjjwalSingh - another bug, has your stack trace, the bit about the missing link, maybe make that manually?