# a jni error has occured

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, java, eclipse

I uninstalled Eclipse IDE due to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456674/eclipse-is-not-running) issue.
Then I tried to run java program in my Linux mint Terminal.
So I started with a small code

```
public class Myth{
public static void main(String[]args){
System.out.println("Hii There");
  }
}
```

and run it by giving commands `javac Myth.java`
and `java Myth` but insted of giving output it gives the following error

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=Myth, offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:729)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:95)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1184)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:732)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:604)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:926)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:871)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:343)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:854)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:507)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

means, that some of the libraries in your project are using diferrent version of java , and set accordingly in path.
Quick things to resolve this:

```
$>which java
```

output->location of current java (eg. /usr/bin/java)

```
java --version
```

output->1.7.0 or 1.8.0
if this is the case , try switching version, for this do the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path to diff java version sdk>
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This allows new path to come in front of old path, also for eclipse specific errors, take a look at eclipse cache in home directory(.eclipse folder in your project). You may safely delete this directory along ith .project files if any and recompile.

Edit: Offset=6 means your current version for java(JDK) is 1.6. Try switching it to later versions. Also check that you are using Jdk path and not jre path

Comment: after the command `java --version` terminal gives the following output `JVMJ9VM007E Command-line option unrecognised: --version
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: java -v, would also do it, there should be no spaces. If it is then your current java path is something like (/usr/java/jre1.x.y/) instead it should be (usr/java/jdk/1.x.y)

Comment: my java path is `/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171` and after changing that the error is still active

Comment: change it to /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_171 . If you dont have a jdk installed get it from oracle site by accepting icense agreement, its free.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html
see java jdk 1.8 u171, and download jdk

Comment: i have `openjdk-11-headless` installed and after changing `/usr/java/jre_xy_z` to `/usr/java/jdk_xy_z` the problem is same

Comment: That is strange which distro are you using and is it 32 bit or 64 bit?
Also see that open jdk isnt a favoured choice for jdk downloads IMO.

Comment: I am using linux mint 19 x64

Comment: Try this:
    javac -target 1.6 Myth.java

Comment: it shows that`javac: target release 1.6 conflicts with default source release 1.10
`

Comment: @UjjwalSingh , You need to find a mismatch version library that is causing issues , since it is hello world program, i dont expect any third party library in your project, This depends on type of project you selected at start.

Comment: Reinstalled jdk and now it is working . Thanks @PavanKate