# Problems in running eclipse

Tags: linux-mint, eclipse

When I download and run Eclipse using

```
$sudo apt install eclipse
```

It shows these errors as in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456674/eclipse-is-not-running).

But when I run `eclipse photon` from their website it works fine.

1. What's the difference between these two?
2. Eclipse from [their website](http://eclipse.org) freezes. Is there any way to fix this?
3. Is there any way to run Eclipse juno from `ppa repository` ?

System info is given below 
[image: System Info]

Answer (score 2):

When you run:

```
$sudo apt install eclipse
```

You are downloading Eclipse from the software package repositories of your operating system ( which I presume is Ubuntu or similar).

The version of Eclipse in the software repositories of Ubuntu/Debian is not updated much and tends to be very old compared to the version of eclipse available on [eclipse.org](https://www.eclipse.org).
Take a look at the version of eclipse in Debian and Ubuntu's package repositories:

[image: Version of eclipse in Debian]

[image: Version of eclipse in Ubuntu]

You can see that the version is 3.8 which is Eclipse `Juno` while the latest is `Photon`.

When you are installing Eclipse from the website of [eclipse.org](https://www.eclipse.org) you are running the latest package offered by [eclipse.org](https://www.eclipse.org) which is Photon.

So the clear difference being the versions of Eclipse. Software repository of Ubuntu is providing an older version, while the website provides the latest version.

The difference between 3.8 (Juno) and 4.8 (Photon) is about 6 releases, and between six releases of lot things change.

You are getting the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:` error, because of a lot of code base has deviated between the six releases. Also the code base of JRE/JDK has changed as well. I will not try to look into what has changed because six releases are a lot.

You better uninstall any Eclipse versions from the repositories and only use the one from the website.

Comment: I just added that part